# Split the string till specific substring

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a reference list. I have to compare author's name with citation authors in the reference list. I have to split the string till the year, so I can get only author names, but I don't have an idea how to proceed further.

For example, given the following text:

> Sperrin, M., Jaki, T., & Wit, E. (2010). Probabilistic relabelling strategies for the label switching problem in Bayesian mixture models. Statistics in Computing, 20, 357-366.

I have to extract the author name:

```
Dim txt As String
Dim txtarray() As String
txt = "Sperrin, M., Jaki, T., & Wit, E. (2010). Probabilistic relabelling strategies for the label switching problem in Bayesian mixture models. Statistics in Computing, 20, 357-366."
txtarray = Split(txt, ",")

//Split will split the entire text, and I need the text only until the year
```

Expected output: `txtarray = ("Sperrin", " M.", " Jaki", " T.","  & Wit")`

Comment: Which author's name do you want? I can see three. Is your string always in same format i.e. { author(s) } { year } { description } { journal } { edition } { pages }

Comment: Author and year will be in same format. Rest of them may vary. I have updated my expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub GetAuthors()
    Dim txt As String, authors As String, authorsArray() As String

    txt = "Sperrin, M., Jaki, T., & Wit, E. (2010). Probabilistic relabelling strategies for the label switching problem in Bayesian mixture models. Statistics in Computing, 20, 357-366."
    authors = VBA.Trim(VBA.Mid$(txt, 1, InStr(1, txt, "(", vbTextCompare) - 1))
    authorsArray = VBA.Split(authors, ",")
End Sub
```

Basically this searches for the first `(` to find where the date starts, creates a substring of the authors only, and the splits it on `,`.

Clearly this only works if the date is present and of the format `(YYYY)`

Comment: It is a word application. Can I know in place of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Search` what should i replace?